# Display full recipient list (To and CC) while composing in Gmail

Tags: gmail

The new Gmail compose has a behavior whereby it collapse the "To" and "CC" recipients and then hides some of them to fit on one line.

Is there a way to disable this behavior and show **all** recipients while composing?

Answer (score 2):

You can show from address in Gmail's compose view by switching to the old Gmail interface using the browser extension [Retro Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk/) (Chrome), [Old Compose](http://oldcompose.com/) (Chrome+Firefox), or [Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg/):

[image]